# Why does this F# / OCaml "match" expression compile?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, ocaml

This code compiles just fine in F# as well as OCaml:

```
let testmatch k =
    match k with
    | jqk3jtl23jtlk123 -> true
```

I've tested in both FSI and utop. It always returns `true`.

The `jqk3jtl23jtlk123` is totally random, and its type is inferred as `'a`. Even if I constrain `k` with a datatype (e.g. `let testmatch (k: int) =`) it compiles (though obviously constraining `testmatch`'s type to `int -> bool` instead of `'a -> bool`.

Could someone please explain what's going on? Specifically:

- why does the compiler accept a totally random literal `jqk3jtl23jtlk123`?
- why do I not get an inexhaustive match warning?
- what is the match actually doing?

Comment: You're not matching against the value `jqk3jtl23jtlk123`, you're creating a value named `jqk3jtl23jtlk123` that matches whatever `k` is.

Comment: In these languages you are usually either in a value expression or a pattern matching expression, and these two behave differently. Pattern matching happens after `match ... with`, after `function`, and in any function/method parameters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, the "literal" `jqk3jtl23jtlk123` is a valid variable name, and so what the pattern to the left of `->` describes is the same as if you wrote `let jqk3jtl23jtlk123 = k`. Since this accepts any value of `k`, and does not constrain its type because binding works for all types, the inferred type is `'a`, the most generic value the type system can represent.

If you turn the literal into something that is not a valid identifier, for example beginning with a digit, it will fail to compile.

If you wrap the literal in quotes, it will be interpreted as a string value literal, you should get the inexhaustive match warning, and it will constrain `k`'s type to `string`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a wildcard pattern, which names whatever `k` is equal to. This is equivalent to

```
let testmatch k =
    let jqk3jtl23jtlk123 = k in
    true
```